How to prove that the integral $\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin x^2}{1+x^p} d x \quad(p \geqslant 0)$ converges uniformly?
To prove that the integral
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin x^2}{1+x^p} d x \quad(p \geqslant 0)
$$
converges uniformly, let's analyze the convergence for different ranges of $p$.
My Attempt:
my considered the case when $p \geqslant 2$ :
$$
\frac{\left|\sin x^2\right|}{1+x^p} \leq \frac{1}{1+x^2}
$$
Since the integral
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^2} d x
$$
converges, by the Comparison Test, the integral
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin x^2}{1+x^p} d x
$$
also converges uniformly for $p \geqslant 2$.
Difficulty Handling $0 \leqslant p \leqslant 1+\delta(\delta>0)$ :(actually I dont konw how to hand the case $0 \leqslant p \leqslant 1+\delta(\delta>0)$ )

Abel test will work:
Firstly,
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \sin x^2 dx$$
is convergent.
Secondly,
$f(x,p)=\frac{1}{1+x^p}$ is decreasing with respect to $x$ for every $p\geq0$,
also we have
$$0<f(x,p)=\frac{1}{1+x^p}\leq1,\quad \forall(x,p)\in[0,\infty)\times[0,+\infty).$$So Abel test implies
$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sin x^2}{1+x^p} d x$$
converges uniformly with respect to $p\in[0,\infty)$.
